# Opening fancybox with a function

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

if i have a ja code

```
$('#fbox').fancybox({
    'width'         :   '50%',
    'type'          :   'iframe'
});
```

and a html code

```
<a href="login.php" id="fbox" class="info fancybox.iframe" 
    onclick="$.fancybox(this);return false;">Login</a>
```

How to open the fancybox with a function

```
function openLoginFancybox() {
   //???
}
```

Then i can use onClick="openLoginFancybox()"

Thank you

Comment: You can use the hooks for that. Take a look at onStart or onComplete http://fancybox.net/api

Answer (score 0):

I want to use this function with a gmap:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    if(!isLoggedIn) {
        openLoginFancybox();
    } else {
        startMarkerPlacing();
    }
});
```

i.e. a function outside from a fancybox json.

Comment: is this your answer? ... otherwise you should edit your question and add these info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I have changed your codes as follows:

HTML:

```
<a href="login.php" id="fbox" onClick="openLoginFancybox(this); return false;">Login</a>​
```

JS:

```
function openLoginFancybox(linkObj) {
    $.fancybox.open({ 
        href : $(linkObj).attr("href"), 
        type : 'iframe',
        width : '50%'
    });
}​
```

-- end code --

Hope this helps.